# How to fix a nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I am investigating why I am getting this error with my Python Discord bot. I'm using Python in VScode with the Nextcord library. It works a bit and them throws this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command <nextcord.application_command.SlashApplicationCommand object at 0x000002379C4C7730>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 863, in invoke_callback_with_hooks
    await self(interaction, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jonat\OneDrive\Documents\DiscordBot\main.py", line 53, in arem
    await interaction.response.send_message("||**Cal Jordan:** Instant message from... AREM!!||", files=[nextcord.File('AREM.mp3')])
  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nextcord\interactions.py", line 895, in send_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nextcord\webhook\async_.py", line 204, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
nextcord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

Comment: Might readers need to see some code, to help them replicate the issue?

Comment: It's not letting me add the code because its to much

Comment: Part of the trick is cutting down the code sample(s) to the smallest samples needed to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unknown interaction" pretty much always means you are taking too long to respond.

Discord allows 3 seconds to respond. If you want to extend that, you can use `await interaction.response.defer()` at the beginning of the function to show "bot is thinking" for up to 15 minutes to allow you time to respond.

See https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html#deferred-response for more info.